# Union of infinite events in a darts game

Tags: probability

Considering a darts game.
There is an infinite number of points so the probability of throwing a dart on one point is 0.

Now if we take an "infinite number of events" where each event is a point.
Then the Union of this "infinite number of events" is the whole sample space (right ?).

And also the probability of union of the "infinite number of events" is the sum of the probability of each event (0)
So the probability of an "infinite number of events" is 0 because the infinite sum of 0 is 0 (right ?).
but the probability of the universe is 1

Someone can explain to me where am I wrong in my reasoning.

Comment: You say *"There is an infinite number of points so the probability of throwing a dart on one point is $0$"* but consider tossing a coin until you  see Heads.  There are an infinite number of possible tosses you might need (any positive integer), but the probability of each outcome is not $0$.  You need to consider what kind of infinity you are looking at.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in the claim `the probability of union of the "infinite number of events" is the sum of the probability of each event`. That claim is simply false.

A weaker version of it is true: the probability of union of **countable** number of **disjoint** events is the sum of the probability of each event. But in your example, the set of points is not countable, so you can't use that statement for it.

Generally, that's the situation in continuous probability spaces - the probability of each particular result is $0$, but a big set of results can have a positive probability.

In your dartboard example, the probability of a set is proportional to its area, so maybe it would be easier to think about the areas. We see the same phenomenon: the area of each point is $0$, but the area of the whole board is positive, even though it only consists of points. (In fact, both `area` and `probability` are special cases of what we call `measure`)

Answer (score 0):

When we consider the probability of a union of an infinite number of events occurring, we appeal to the countable additivity of the probability measure. Namely, if we have a countable collection of events $(E_i)_{i\in \mathbb{N}}$ that are pairwise disjoint, then
$$\mathbb{P}\left( \bigcup_{i\in\mathbb{N}} E_i\right)=\sum_{i=1}^\infty \mathbb{P}(E_i).$$
From this property of the probability measure, you can obtain the result you are looking for!

Comment: That means that my problem is about the uncountable part of the coordinate system I'm using for a darts game, But if we replace the dart board with an infinite line of holes that map \N, so now the coordinate system is countable. Is a probability of a dart in one hole still 0?

Comment: @Faulheit What the probability of a dart hitting a certain point is is not a mathematical question. Math can't answer that. That is something that needs to come from another place (like physics). What math can do is, under certain conditions regarding these probabilities, make a theory of how to find reasonable probabilities of (some) combination of events. In this case, you have discovered the fact that you cannot choose an integer (or a natural number) "unifiormly at random", that means with equal probability for each number.

Comment: If that probability was positive, the probability of hitting anything would be infinite. If it was zero, the probability of hitting anything would also be zero, which is not what is intended. It is of course possible to assign non-equal probabilities that sum to $1$, for example, when the holes  are at the positions of positive integers, assign $n$ the probability of being hit $1/2^n$.